# line break inside text with defined font

Tags: fonts, line-breaking

I'm not sure if this is the right description.
I have the default font that is applied in the whole document. And I have a font that I call inside the command \teacher{}.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\cur}[1]{{\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont #1}}

\begin{center}
    {\Huge \color{blue!90!green!50}{\textbf{Title}}}
\end{center}
 
\bigskip 

\newcommand{\teacher}[1]{
\tikz[baseline]{
\draw (0,0) node[left=0.3cm,align=center,fill=violet!20,draw=violet,rounded corners,line width=2pt,inner sep=5pt] {\cur{#1}}
 }
}

\newcommand{\lteacher}[1]{
\tikz[baseline]{
\draw (0,0) node[left=0.3cm,align=center,fill=violet!20,draw=violet,rounded corners,line width=2pt,inner sep=5pt] {#1} 
 }
}


Normal text.\\

\bigskip

%test%
\teacher{This is line 1.\\ This is line 2.}\\

\bigskip

\lteacher{\cur{This is line 1.}\\ \cur{This is line 2.}}





\end{document}
```

What I want is to be able to do a linebreak inside the 1st commande \teacher{} not \lteacher.

This is what I get with the MWE (the first command clearly generates an error):
[image]

Comment: Please post something we can test. We don't have the `teacher.png` file. And is the big, centred title relevant?

Comment: the teacher.png isn't relevant, I tried to trim a long text I had, I forgot a few details. The title isn't relevant either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `font=\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont` in the node options. It will apply the font to all lines of a multi-line node.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}

\begin{document}        
    
    \newcommand{\cur}[1]{{\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont #1}}      
    
    \newcommand{\teacher}[1]{%
        \tikz[baseline]{%
            \draw (0,0) node[left=0.3cm,align=center,fill=violet!20,draw=violet,rounded corners,line width=2pt,
            inner sep=5pt,
            font=\fontfamily{qzc}\selectfont %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            ] {#1}
        }
    }
    
    \newcommand{\lteacher}[1]{%
        \tikz[baseline]{%
            \draw (0,0) node[left=0.3cm,align=center,fill=violet!20,draw=violet,rounded corners,line width=2pt,inner sep=5pt] {#1} 
        }
    }
    
    
    Normal text.\\
    
    \bigskip
    
    %test%
    \teacher{This is line 1.\\ This is line 2.}\\
    
    \bigskip
    
    \lteacher{\cur{This is line 3.}\\ \cur{This is line 4.}}
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You shouldn't have `\\ ` after `Normal text.` @stargazer45