# Vertical mode inside a Tikz node, with \textit or \emph

Tags: line-breaking, italic, tikz-node

I want to write a two- or multiple-line text in italic inside a tikz node. But I always get an error. Please help me with this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}


\newcommand{\teacher}[1]{
\tikz[baseline]{
\draw (0,0) node[left=0.35cm,align=center,fill=violet!20,draw=violet,rounded corners,line width=1pt,inner sep=5pt] {\textit{#1}}   node[circle,fill=violet!20,draw=violet,line width=1pt,inner sep=1pt] {\Large \color{red}\faCheck}; 
 }
}


\begin{document}

\teacher{Hello\\World}


\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Never say 'I get an error' in posts. Tell us which error you get. What is the exact text of the error message? But, as noted, this appears to be the same as your earlier question.

Comment: @campa there's no font here to specify, or at least not at my knowledge. It's just the default font but in italic.

Comment: Italic *is* a different font.

Comment: @cfr you're right about the error, but as I said, the earlier question solved one problem, but it didn't work here, I don't know how to adapt it to this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the `align` key the node's content is typeset in a `\box`. When `align` is used, the text is basically put into a `tabular` (actually in a TeX primitive `\halign`). Therefore, when you write

```
\tikz\node[draw,align=left]{foo\\bar};
```

the content of the node becomes something like

```
\begin{tabular}{l}foo\\bar\end{tabular}
```

If you wrap the node's text in a macro

```
\tikz\node[draw,align=left]{\textit{foo\\bar}};
```

it's like you were writing

```
\begin{tabular}{l}\textit{foo\\bar}\end{tabular}
```

and chaos will ensue.

What to do? You've already been advised in your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/699317/82917) to use the `font` key. That advice holds also here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\newcommand{\teacher}[1]{%
   \tikz[baseline]{%
      \draw (0,0) node[left=0.35cm,align=center,fill=violet!20,draw=violet,rounded corners,line width=1pt,inner sep=5pt,font=\itshape] {#1}
      node[circle,fill=violet!20,draw=violet,line width=1pt,inner sep=1pt] {\Large\color{red}\faCheck};%                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   }%
}

\begin{document}

\teacher{Hello\\World}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @campa. It works.
Yes I know the solution to the other question. I simply didn't know that \itshape keyword and that italic was considered anothre font. Thanks again for your explanation.